# How i get variable value saved in database?

Tags: php, codeigniter

i had save data in mysql data base and i had create template html tags in one column. now i want to display template data in php, but its not working.

MYSQL DATABASE IMAGE CLICK HEAR TO SHOW DATABASE
[image]

Controller

```
class Project extends CI_Controller{

    function template(){
        $query = $this-db->query("select * from templete where id='11' ");
        $result = $query->result_array();
        $data['result'] = $result[0];

        $this->load->view('template_view',$data);
    }
}
```

View

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<?php
    extract($result);

    echo $template_data;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Output :

```
{$ticker}
{$address1}
{$address2}
{$city}
{$phone}
{$website}
```

I want output

```
HSPG.OL
SparebankgÃƒÂ¥rden
BjÃƒÂ¸rkelangen
http://www.hsbank.no
```

template data dyanamic 
its gone be

```
<p>{$ticker}</p><p>{$address1}</p><p>{$address2}</p><p>{$city}</p><p>{$phone}</p><p>{$website}</p>
```

or

```
<p>{$ticker}</p><p>{$address1}</p><p>{$address2}</p><p>{$city}</p>
```

any one help, i am post this question 2nd time with full coding.

Comment: php extract function is doing what it is supposed to. it is showing what you have in your table

Comment: Click here ->   http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

Comment: array
(
 [template_data] => "<p>{$ticker}</p><p>{$address1}</p><p>{$address2}</p><p>{$city}</p><p>{$phone}</p><p>{$website}</p>
 [date] => 2017-03-01
    [ticker] => HSPG.OL
    [address1] => SparebankgÃ¥rden
    [address2] => 
    [city] => BjÃ¸rkelangen
    [state] => 
    [zip] => 1940
    [country] => Norway
    [phone] => 
    [website] => http://www.hsbank.no
    [industry] => Money Center Banks
    [sector] => Financial
    [fulltimeemployees] => 
    [longbusinesssummary] => 
)
convert to 

$template_data
$date
$ticker
and so on

Answer (score 0):

Although Codeigniter as a framework doesn't stop you or restrict you to stay in MVC boundaries but it is really appreciated and a good practice that one should do so.

**BEST PRACTICE**

> Create a model and put your query in a function in that model. Call
>   that function in your controller, get your data in an array/object and
>   then send it to the view that's how MVC is supposed to be.

In your case, you are using php extract() function to get data out of the $result array which it has done perfectly but what you are printing is not the correct index.

[Read this](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_extract.asp) for php extract info

so instead of printing $template_data use the following ;

```
<html>
<head></head>
 <body>
 <?php
    extract($result);

    echo $ticker.'<br>';
    echo $address1.'<br>';
    echo $city.'<br>'; // and so on
 ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: template data dyanamic 
its gone be <p>{$ticker}</p><p>{$address1}</p><p>{$address2}</p><p>{$city}</p><p>{$phone}</p><p>{$website}</p>
or  <p>{$ticker}</p><p>{$address1}</p><p>{$address2}</p><p>{$city}</p>

Comment: though I see no reason for making your architecture like this but still what you can do is delete the < p> tags from template_data column and just save those values either comma separated or space and then use your extract function, Use paragraph or any other styling tag in view. that will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Lot of things wrong with this code. You shouldn't be getting template data from the database, that should be in the view. You should probably delete the template_data column from your table.

```
class Project extends CI_Controller{

    function template(){
        $query = $this-db->query("select * from templete where id='11' ");
        $data['result'] = $query->result_array();

        $this->load->view('template_view',$data);
    }
}
```

View:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<?php echo $result['ticker'];   ?>
<?php echo $result['address1'] . ' ' . $result['address2'];   ?>
<?php echo $result['city'];   ?>
<?php echo $result['phone'];   ?>
<?php echo $result['website'];   ?>
?>   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: template data dyanamic 
its gone be <p>{$ticker}</p><p>{$address1}</p><p>{$address2}</p><p>{$city}</p><p>{$phone}</p><p>{$website}</p>
or  <p>{$ticker}</p><p>{$address1}</p><p>{$address2}</p><p>{$city}</p>

Comment: Not sure if you read my answer, you should delete the template_data column, it's a bad practice. All the data you need is in the other columns, you just need to create a view that accesses that data correctly.